# junit test and web service

Tags: java, web-services, junit

I have a test unit that tests crud for web service but I'm having a problem. When I run all the tests all work, but when I run all of them at the same time the test of publications (for example) I can not update or recover because it gives 500 error, but if I run only one at a time it works. What should I do to be able to do everything at once?

```
//@Ignore
    @Test
    public void inserirPublicacao() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        int code = 0;

        PublicacaoDao dao = new PublicacaoDao();
        Publicacao pb = new Publicacao();

        String localidade = "br 212";
        String descricao = "selvagens na estrada";
        long idUsuario = 2;

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        //Armazena dados em um Objeto JSON
        jsonObject.put("localidade", localidade);
        jsonObject.put("descricao", descricao);
        jsonObject.put("codigo", idUsuario);    

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String Json = gson.toJson(jsonObject);

        URL url;

            url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/DivulgueAqui/webresources/webService/pb/inserir");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(Json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();

            code = connection.getResponseCode();

            os.close();
            connection.disconnect();

            pb = dao.recuperar((long)5);

        assertEquals(204,code);
        assertEquals(pb.getDescricao(),descricao);
        assertEquals(pb.getLocalidade(),localidade);
    }

   // @Ignore
    @Test
    public void atualizarPublicacao() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        int code = 0;
        String descricao = "nevasca pequena";
        String localidade = "nunca menos";
        long codigo = 1;//codigo da publicacao

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        //Armazena dados em um Objeto JSON
        jsonObject.put("descricao", descricao);
        jsonObject.put("localidade", localidade);
        jsonObject.put("codigo", codigo);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String Json = gson.toJson(jsonObject);

        URL url;

            url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/DivulgueAqui/webresources/webService/pb/update");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(Json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();

            code = connection.getResponseCode();

            os.close();
            connection.disconnect();

        assertEquals(200,code);
    }

   // @Ignore
    @Test
    public void recuperarPublicacoesPorIdDoUsuario() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        int code = 0;

        long codigo = 2; // id do usuario
            URL url;

            url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/DivulgueAqui/webresources/webService/pb/listaTodasPorIdUsuario?id="+codigo);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            code = connection.getResponseCode();

        assertEquals(200,code);
    }

   // @Ignore
    @Test 
    public void deletarPublicacao() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        int code = 0;
        URL url;

         Integer codigo = 2;   

            url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/DivulgueAqui/webresources/webService/pb/delete?id="+codigo);//codigo


            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");

            code = connection.getResponseCode();

        assertEquals(204,code);
    }
```

That's what I do if I run it all together

```
atualizarPublicacao(testesUnitários.TesteWebServicePublicacao)  Time elapsed: 0.296 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<500>
    at testesUnitários.TesteWebServicePublicacao.atualizarPublicacao(TesteWebServicePublicacao.java:122)

recuperarPublicacoesPorIdDoUsuario(testesUnitários.TesteWebServicePublicacao)  Time elapsed: 0.313 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<500>
    at testesUnitários.TesteWebServicePublicacao.recuperarPublicacoesPorIdDoUsuario(TesteWebServicePublicacao.java:142)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  TesteWebServicePublicacao.atualizarPublicacao:122 expected:<200> but was:<500>
  TesteWebServicePublicacao.recuperarPublicacoesPorIdDoUsuario:142 expected:<200> but was:<500>
```

The problem that I run individually works everything

Comment: Is there dependencies between your test?

Comment: `Publicacao pb = new Publicacao();` not the correct way to do it.. you are not suppose to create onjects of external dependencies.

Comment: Scary Wombat Thus, a publication can only be published by a user
This is where I spend long idUsuario = 2; In the web service I search for this user and put the user object inside the punctuation table

Comment: Jobin ok, later I get it right

Comment: The interesting thing is that if I test one at a time it works but if I test everything together, it will not. I do not know if tomcat supports all these requirements. ..